# setonitemclicklistener not working for gridview

Tags: android, gridview, onitemclicklistener

Here's My Code the code, I'm not getting any response from gridview setOnClickListener.
Please Help me out.

```
setContentView(R.layout.myfav);
gView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    context = MyFav.this;
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    gView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());
    // save.setOnClickListener(this);
    // cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    gView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("inside click", "" + arg2);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello" + arg2,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

This is my Grid view

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
</GridView>
```

Comment: is your gridview showing perfectly after adding the adapter ??

Comment: ya. All the items are showing correctly

Comment: then what problem you are facing here as I saw all are fine here.

Comment: is the log message show something after clicking on the item?

Comment: No Log is not showing related to click

Comment: just try JstnPwll answer i.e android:focusableInTouchMode="false" in your xml .

Comment: Make sure that the layout for the grid items does not have any `clickable` attributes, especially in the root. Also, do you have any 'clickable' items in your grid items and/or are you setting any other click listeners in your adapter? Might be best to share some of your grid item layout and adapter code.

Comment: can you show your gridview tag that you define in xml.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It could be that some items in your GridView are stealing focus. Try adding these attributes to any elements you have inside the grid:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: This was the answer i needed. One more doubt. i have Check Box in the custom gridview how to get the elements that are checked in it?

Comment: I don't understand. You need to determine whether a checkbox in your grid is checked?

Comment: Initialize the checkbox through your view and check wheather isCheckedor not through checkbox.oncheckedchangelistener..

Comment: I've the items in gridview with checkbox.

Comment: Excellent dude ! You rock !

Comment: Depending on your layout you may have to set `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on the parent layout of the view which is stealing focus